# Outlook 2003 and Exchange 2010 Slow Public Folders

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2003

We have recently put a new Exchange 2010 server in place, and have moved most of our mailboxes and public folders over to it. Our clients are all still on Outlook 2003.

Most things are working ok, they only issue we have is slowness in public folders. We have quite a few public folders the users work in, where they flag/move/etc. emails.

For example, when they are flagging on an email it can now take about 10 seconds for the flag to actually appear on the message for the user that has clicked it, so they are getting a bit frustrated as this never used to happen.

I have found the article about enabling UDP messages again (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009942) which we have done, but it didn't seem to make any difference. Although I'm not sure if we have to restart after applying the reg key.

Has anyone any ideas what might be causing it, or how we can speed it up?